# How do I create a Custom Keyboard having only Alphabets, Space Bar and a Comma?

Tags: swiftui, keyboard

**Scenario:** User can enter only words (ex usage: states, counties, etc.) separated by commas and spaces into a text field.  Any numerics or special characters is pollution.

I want to reduce amount of filtering garage entered.  Hence the custom keyboard.

The closest is the Alphabets keyboard; but it lacks the comma key.

**Question:** How do I customize a keyboard in SwiftUI; or do I have to used the UIViewControllerRepresentable or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.0 iOS 14

You don't need a custom keyboard, you just need to filter the data as it comes in.

Here an example filtering numbers only.

import SwiftUI

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var name: String = "PIN"

var body: some View {
    VStack {
      TextField("Enter your name:", text: $name)
        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        .onChange(of: name) { newValue in
          if !(name.last?.isNumber ?? true) {
            name.removeLast()
          }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
}
```

Wrote a paper about the technique, published on medium.com. This one.

https://medium.com/better-programming/data-validation-in-swiftui-2-0-790cf6dbe49a

Comment: That's a good plan 'B'.  But why allow unwanted characters in the first place?   

My point is to reduce about of filtering as much as possible by merely allowing ONLY alphabets, a comma and space bar.  That could be done with an alphabet keyboard; but the existing alpha template does't have the 'comma'.

I know a keyboard can be customized; but I was hoping to keep it simple rather than overhauling the view controller, etc.

Comment: Using this method you don't have unwanted characters. They hit the key and nothing happens it doesn't work, nothing is reflecting in the input box. If you try and develop your own keyboard what happens when you want to sell this outside the US for example. The French keyboard is different to the US, as is the German one or even the UK one.

Comment: Point taken.   Didn't consider that.